# Nordyne furnace doesn't start at all (model gl1ra 090c-12b 903785GA)

Tags: furnace

What are the reasons this model furnace won't start at all anymore. No sound when I flip the on switch. I already tried replacing the ignitor and that didn't work. Thank you for any help!